# In a complete metric space which has no isolated points, there is no countable dense set is a $G_\delta$

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

I have a question in the proof of that there is no countable dense set is a $G_\delta$ (that is a set of all countable intersection of open set) in a complete metric space $X$ which has no isolated points.
The proof is here:
Let $x_n$ be the points of a countable dense set $E$ in $X$. Assume that $E$ is a $G_\delta$. Then $E=\bigcap V_n$, where each $V_n$ is dense and open since if each $V_n$ is not dense, $E\subset X\subset\bar{E}$ does not hold. Let
$$W_n=V_n-\bigcup_{k=1}^{n} \{x_k\}.$$
Then each $W_n$ is a dense open set, but the intersection of $W_n$ is empty, it contradicts Baire's category theorem.

Question: Why $W_n$ is open and dense?
To check density, we need to check $W_n\subset X\subset \bar{W_n}$, but I couldn't work well. Should I use other definition of density: $E$ is dense in $X$ if every point of $X$ is a limit point of $E$ or a point of $E$?

Comment: It being open is obvious, because all you did was delete finitely many points from an open set. It being dense is also obvious because all you did was delete finitely many points from a dense set, but those points were not isolated, so there are points remaining that are arbitrarily close to the deleted points, so that they are in $\overline{W}_n$. Put it this way: if you're asked about a metric space with no isolated points, picture $\mathbb{R}^n$. Usually either the result is just not true in your space, or the picture is basically the same in $\mathbb{R}^n$ as it is in your space.

Comment: Corollaries:(1)... $\Bbb Q$ is not a $G_{\delta}$ subset of $\Bbb R$...(2)... There is no complete metric for $\Bbb Q$ because of the easier direction of this theorem: Let  $X$ (e.g. $X=\Bbb R$) be completely metrizable and let $Y$ be a sub-space of $X$. Then $Y$ is completely metrizable iff $Y$ is a $G_{\delta}$ subset of $X.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that each $V_n$ is dense simply because $E \subseteq V_n$ and $E$ is dense so $X=\overline{E}\subseteq \overline{V_n} \subseteq X$, so $\overline{V_n}=X$ too.

Every finite set is closed (in a metric space for sure, but this holds for a large class of spaces, the so-called $T_1$ spaces), so each set of the form $X\setminus \{x\}$ is open.

A finite intersection of dense open sets is (open and) dense and any set of the form $X\setminus \{x\}$ is dense (or else $x \notin \overline{X\setminus \{x\}}$ which means $\{x\}$ is open, contradiction)

Now $W_n = V_n \cap (X\setminus \{x_1\}) \cap \ldots \cap (X\setminus \{x_n\})$ is open and dense as a finite intersection of open and dense sets.

Comment: It would be a little easier if we re-defined $W_n$ as $V_n\setminus \{x_n\}$ at the start

Answer (score 1):

In a metric space ,a finite set is closed,so each $W_n$ is an intersection of two open sets.
Also since $\bigcup_{k=1}^n\{x_k\}$ is finite then $W_n$ is dense since you can find a sequence in $V_n$ that converges to $x_k, \forall k \in \{1,2...n\}$ by density of $V_n$